# Window problems in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-windowmanager

I am planning to perform a Rotating Animation on a two directional scroll view (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866499/two-directional-scroll-view)). I have got the effect of the 2 directional scroll view, but now when i perform a Filp3D Type of animation (see [link](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html)) i am getting a rotating window !

i actually wanted to perform a rotation around x-axis animation and then perform successive animation.

My Code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ScrollView sv;
WScrollView hsv;
Animation anim;
RelativeLayout rl;
Button b1,b2,b3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

/*BIDIRECTIONAL SCROLLVIEW*/
    sv = new ScrollView(this);
    hsv = new WScrollView(this);
    hsv.sv = sv;
    /*END OF BIDIRECTIONAL SCROLLVIEW*/

    rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.interactivemap);
    sv.addView(rl, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    hsv.addView(sv, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT /*or FILL_PARENT if API < 8*/));
    setContentView(hsv);

    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setLayout(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    /* Animation Effects : Stage I */

    applyRotation(0, 45);

    /* Animation Effects : Stage II */
    /* Still to perform ! */
}

private void applyRotation(final float start, final float end) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final float centerX = hsv.getWidth() / 2.0f + hsv.getLeft();
            final float centerY = hsv.getHeight() / 2.0f + hsv.getTop();
            Log.e("center-x center-y ",centerX+"  "+centerY+"found");
            final Flip3dAnimation rotation = new Flip3dAnimation(start, end, centerX, centerY);
            rotation.setDuration(2000);
            rotation.setFillAfter(true);
            rotation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            hsv.startAnimation(rotation);

        }
    }, 10);
}
}
```

**Output :**
**1)** The output is sometimes an animation around a different axis and then it becoming invisible, as if i have not put any setFillAfter(true), which happens to present in the Flip3dAnimation Class as shown in the two directional scroll view link.
**2)** The Animation comes and persists but only the original window is rotated in the 3d space, as if a card has flip 45 degrees !

I need the second Output with any window restrictions, as i have used a scroll view (2d), i want to be visible like a 2d plane as in a game like AOE (Age of Empires, seriously, people play games :D), or for non-games, a open 2d surface.

Please guide me for achieving the same, also please direct me to some source code which performs complex 2d animations for API-8 or 9.