# Scrollable background and buttons on android main activity

Tags: java, android, dictionary, background, scrollable

I am trying to build an app where the main activity involves a scrollable subway map. It will have buttons integrated on every subway station. I am stuck because I have no idea how to make a background scrollable, furthermore, allowing my buttons to scroll with the background. I also need the scrolling to scroll in x and y dimensions.

Comment: "Any input wuold be much appreciated. :D" - exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `ScrollView` and then throw whatever your layout is inside of it (note that it can only have one child) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

EDIT: Never mind, I didn't realize you needed 2D scrolling but thankfully there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866499/two-directional-scroll-view/8035250#8035250)